# Same keystore, but different keys for different apps?

Tags: android, signing

Ok so I understand I can use the same keystore for multiple apps, but what about the same KEY or ALIAS? Should I use the same keystore AND same alias or key for all of my apps?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to use the same keystore and alias for multiple apps.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use the same alias for your apps. But for the same app when publishing updates my understanding is that you have to use the same keystore/alias. Now, which approach is better? Depends, however signing apps with the same key establishes the trust among your applications in sharing data. From android developer's website:

*The Android system uses the certificate as a means of identifying the author of an application and establishing trust relationships between applications.*

Comment: I know you don't have to but should you?

Comment: i would say yes and a good reason for that is the secure communication among your applications installed in one device