# Couldn't activate Google Maps API v2 in release version

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I can't activated my Google Maps v2 Android API in my release version :(

My debug version working correctly. I published my app **(Android APP BUNDLE)** in closed test channel and I get following error in logcat:

> 2018-10-24 13:21:50.255 6704-6769/? E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
>
> 2018-10-24 13:21:50.257 6704-6769/? E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
>
> Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
>
> Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
>
> API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
>
> Android Application (cert_fingerprint>;package_name>): 74:4E:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:05:2A;com.soft.test

And this is my ".../main/res/values/google_maps_api.xml":

```
<resources>

    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXM1mI</string>

</resources>
```

I have following fingerprints in my API Console:

[image: Google API Console]

My build.gradle (Module:app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.soft.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "@string/version"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

I am working on this problem for days. Searching web, reading stackoverflow answers, uploading test versions to google play but can't find any solution :(

I have three main questions:

1. I have API KEY in my google_maps_api.xml but logcat error still says "API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE" which looks like app cannot see API_KEY. Why? ( I think this can be main solution of my problem)
2. In logcat error and "keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore" command output, I got two different fingerprints? How can this possible? (I'm sure I run command on true keystore)
3. Main question: What is wrong with me, or with Google? How can I activate MAP API for release version?

Comment: did you replace API_KEY in your manifest?

Comment: did you enable Maps SDK for Android  APl from google play console

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, no I didn't. Where must I write It? But debug version works correctly.

Comment: @Radesh, I wrote it in main and debug .xml. manifest has "android:value="@string/google_maps_key"

Comment: @Kuvalya You can add this in manifest section, `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` . FYI, make sure you create proper RELEASE KEY

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari, yes I enabled MAPS SDK, and it works correctly for debug version.

Comment: please share your biuld.gradle app level

Comment: Same problem if you uninstall app and run again?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, yes. Uninstall, install, close-open phone. republish with different package name. Same problem I got :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465868/same-keystore-but-different-keys-for-different-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error and solution.

First, I hard coded API KEY to manifest file, and it worked. Then I realized that, there is no google_maps_api.xml file in release directory.

I added google_maps_api.xml file to release directory manually.  Unfortunately, still can't see release version of google_maps_api.xml file in Android view:

[image: screenshot]

But, Android Studio generated App Bundle with release directory file. And I published a correctly working version in Google Play: [PETAROUND](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whitehillsoft.petaround). :)

I think there is a bug in Android Studio. I'm using Android Studio Build:3.2.1, on macOS 10.13.6 HighSierra. Now, I'm looking and searching this bug. I will write it here if I find any answer about bug.